# Ruby - Adding value to hash adds duplicate data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multidimensional-array, hash

When I access my nested hash something weird happens.
Below is my nested hash.

```
{
  "http://example.com"=>{
     "a-big_word"=>{
        "Another word"=>[]
     }
}, 
  "www.example.com"=>{
     "a-big_word"=>{
        "Another word"=>[]
     }
  }
}
```

If I try and add something to it with the following

`hash['www.example.com']['a-big_word']['Another word'] << {"key"=>"value"}`

This happens

```
   {
      "http://example.com"=>{
         "a-big_word"=>{
            "Another word"=>[{"key"=>"value"}]
         }
    }, 
      "www.example.com"=>{
         "a-big_word"=>{
            "Another word"=>[{"key"=>"value"}]
         }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure about the key names? you said you are using the form `hash["www.example.com"]["sublink"]["hi"]`, however the correct form is `hash[:"www.example.com"][:sublink][:hi]` see the difference ? ... symbols!

Comment: You might be influenced by another language, like JavaScript. In Ruby, you should use the operator `=>` when the keys are not symbols. Also what you got is a nested `Hash` and not `a multi-dimensional`   `{name goes here}`

Comment: if the keys are in quotes should it always be `[:"key"]`? I am getting `undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: not always, one use the form `:"key"` when `key` has special (but valid) characters, like dots `.`.  This worked for me without changing your code `hash[:"www.example.com"][:sublink][:hi] << 'as'` check it out.

Comment: I made it a little more simple in my example above, my keys all have spaces, `-`, `.`, etc in them should I do it in the format `hash[:"www.example.com"][:"sublink"][:"hi"] << 'as'`

Comment: Don't use symbols then, it's too much trouble. I'll post an answer.

Comment: Thank you! Hashes always seem to confuse me :(

Comment: Your code examples are too noisy, you should try to reproduce the issue with the less amount of code posible (Most of the cases doing so you end up solving the issue on your own). Also the way you are initialising the `Hash` is not using _Ruby syntax_.

Comment: @fguillen I have made my question and code example easier to understand

Comment: As you can see I can't reproduce your issue: http://ideone.com/UdcWSh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use strings instead of symbols as keys. I took your hash and changed the keys to be strings. Now it looks like this:

```
{"http://example.com"=>
   {"sublink"=>
      {"A word"=>[], :"Another word"=>[]},
   "sublinktwo"=>
      {"Hello"=>[], "World"=>[]}},
 "www.example.com"=>
   {"sublink"=>
      {"hi"=>[], "goodbye"=>[]},
    "sublinkthree"=>
      {"word"=>[], "bye"=>[]}
   }
}
```

If you haven't see the difference, for keys I'm using `=>` instead of `:`. In that way Ruby will not convert the keys into symbols, it will leave it as they are.

How to access the values? Check out the following `irb` session.

```
> hash["www.example.com"]
 => {"sublink"=>{"hi"=>[], "goodbye"=>[]}, "sublinkthree"=>{"word"=>[], "bye"=>[]}}
> hash["www.example.com"]["sublink"]
 => {"hi"=>[], "goodbye"=>[]}
> hash["www.example.com"]["sublink"]["hi"]
 => []
```

Change value:

```
> hash["www.example.com"]["sublink"]["hi"] << {"key"=>"value"}
 => [{"key"=>"value"}]
```

Comment: Okay and how would I dynamically create the keys as strings? I am creating the keys in a loop.... e.g. `hash[key] = {}`

Comment: Not sure what you mean... To create a new key just assign a value (any value) to that key inside the `Hash` object. `hash["a key"] = "value"` as you will normally do in JavaScript (though with the ruby syntax in mind). Ruby is very dynamic unlike C or C++, you don't have to reserve memory or anything else whatsoever to create new objects.

Comment: It doesnt seem to be working for me. I have no Idea what I am doing wrong. I will edit my example above to be more clear

Comment: @MaxRose-Collins All the examples are tested, please check your code or put a more complete version of your script.

Comment: Hi, sorry you are right. I just checked how I was building my nested hash and in the loop I was using it was using some keys twice, so that's why I was getting data put into both parts of the hash I assume?